# Specifying a node at the center of each drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following modified code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407449/typesetting-tangram-figures-in-latex)

How can I specify a node at the center of each figure, so that they can be drawn related to the centers of each other, instead of position (0,0).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  big triangle/.pic={
  \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- cycle;
  },
  medium triangle/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0)  -- (1,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle;  
  },
  square/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
  },
  small triangle/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
  },
  parallelogram/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
  }
  }
\tikzset{
  tangram solution/.style={
      fill=none,
    draw=red,
    line width=.1mm
  },   
  tangram/.style={
  transform shape,
    tangram solution
  }
}
\begin{document}
\hskip -2cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\path (0,0) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {big triangle}
--++(0:2) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {parallelogram}
--++(0:1) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {small triangle}
--++(0:1) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {square}
--++(0:1) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {medium triangle}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a manually computed coordinate shift is added to the `\path` in each `pic`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  big triangle/.pic={
    \path[pic actions, shift={(-4/3,-2/3)}] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- cycle;
    \fill circle (1pt); % mark the "center", just for the test
  },
  medium triangle/.pic={
    \path[pic actions, shift={(-1,-1/3)}] (0,0)  -- (1,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle;  
    \fill circle (1pt);
  },
  square/.pic={
    \path[pic actions, shift={(-.5,-.5)}] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
    \fill circle (1pt);
  },
  small triangle/.pic={
    \path[pic actions, shift={(-2/3,-1/3)}] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \fill circle (1pt);
  },
  parallelogram/.pic={
    \path[pic actions, shift={(-1,-.5)}] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
    \fill circle (1pt);
  }
  }
\tikzset{
  tangram solution/.style={
      fill=none,
    draw=red,
    line width=.1mm
  },   
  tangram/.style={
  transform shape,
    tangram solution
  }
}
\begin{document}
\hskip -2cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \path (0,0) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {big triangle}
    -- ++(0:2) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {parallelogram}
    -- ++(0:1) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {small triangle}
    -- ++(0:1) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {square}
    -- ++(0:1) pic[tangram,rotate=0] {medium triangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to (calculate) the position of the center of a drawing, instead of manually making this for each drawing separately.

Comment: Looks like a typical use case for nodes. Then you need to define your own node shapes.

Comment: @– muzimuzhi Z Would you please tell me how to do it, just for one drawing. Thank you.