# Aligning nodes in different pictures relative to each other (to draw Tangram pieces)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code, modified from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407449/typesetting-tangram-figures-in-latex), to align tangram pieces in relation to each other.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lwidth}{.1mm}
\tikzset{
  big trianglea/.pic={
  \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (tbal){} -- (2,0) node (tbar){b} -- (2,2) node (tbat){} -- cycle;
  },
  big triangleb/.pic={
  \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (tbbl){} -- (2,0) node (tbbr){\textcolor {green}x} -- (2,2) node (tbbt){} -- cycle;
  },
  medium triangle/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (tml){} -- (1,1) node (tmt){} -- (2,0) node (tmr){} -- cycle;  
  },
  square/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (sdl){c} -- (1,0) node (sdr){} -- (1,1) node (sur){} -- (0,1) node (sul){} -- cycle;
  },
  small trianglea/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (tsal){} -- (1,0) node (tsar){} -- (1,1) node (tsat){} -- cycle;
  },
  small triangleb/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (tsbl){} -- (1,0) node (tsbr){} -- (1,1) node (tsbt){} -- cycle;
  },
  parallelogram/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (padl){} -- (1,0) node (padr){} -- (2,1) node (paur){} -- (1,1) node (paul){} -- cycle;
  },
  parallelogramr/.pic={%to flip horizontally
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (prdl){a} -- (1,0) node (prdr){} -- (2,-1) node (prur){} -- (1,-1) node (prul){} -- cycle;
  }
}
\tikzset{
  tangram puzzle/.style={
    fill=black,
    draw=black,
    line width=\lwidth
  },
  tangram solution/.style={
      fill=white,%black
    draw=red,%black
    line width=\lwidth
  },   
  tangram/.style={
  transform shape,
    %tangram puzzle
    tangram solution
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\inc]
\pic[tangram,rotate=-63.44] at (0,0) {parallelogramr};
\pic[tangram,rotate=0] at (-.542,-3.236) {square};
\pic[tangram,rotate=-45] at (-1.4142,-3.238) {big trianglea};
\pic[tangram,rotate=135] at (1.4146,-6.068) {big triangleb};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it takes a lot of trials and errors to align `pics` in relation with each other. For example aligning `the square` in position `(-.542,-3.236)`.

Is it possible to easily align `a certain node` in `a certain pic` relative to `a node in another pic`.

For example to align `node (b)` (in pic `trianglea`) and `node (k)` (in pic `triangleb`) relative to `node (a)` (which is located in the pic `parallelogramr`, `node prdl`) using the code `[shift={(-90:6)}prdl.center]`

[image]

Comment: As the linked post said, these were thrown together without consideration of positioning syntax.  My penrose tiles package does have the capability to align tiles alongside each other and one can add new tiles, so it should be possible to use that package for a more sophisticated tangram tiles environment.

Comment: I note that you are using `picture` to refer to `pics` _within_ a single `tikzpicture` rather than in different `tikzpictures`.

Comment: @– Andrew Stacey I downloaded your package, and placed tikzlibrarypenrose.code.tex in the same folder of my tex file, but it did not compile.

Comment: you shouldn't need to download it, it should be part of your TeX distribution.  It depends on other packages so it is best to install it via your distribution.  Also "it did not compile" doesn't exactly make it easy to help!

Comment: @– Andrew Stacey This is the error message I've got when I tried to compile my tex file, after adding \usetikzlibrary{penrose} in the preamble.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6jnj.png

Comment: @Hany Check with the MikTeX console that the `penrose` package is installed, otherwise install it!

Comment: @– AndréC I checked with MikTeX console, and this is its screenshot   https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjY7Y.png   I still got the same error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6jnj.png when compiling my tex file.

Comment: That's a bit odd, still I think that putting `\usepackage{expl3}` before it in your preamble should fix it.

Comment: @– Andrew Stacey I tried it, but it did not work. Can you reply my question without using your package!

Comment: I used MikTeX to design my answer so it compiles just fine with MikTeX. Maybe you need to update your whole distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your pics with the necessary nodes for reference (which you have), it's not very difficult to align the pieces using the `calc` library. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset
{%
  big triangle/.pic={%
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (-A) {} -- ({0.5*sqrt(2)},0)  node (-B) {} -- (0,{0.5*sqrt(2)}) node (-C) {} -- cycle;},
  medium triangle/.pic={%
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (-A) {} -- (0.5,0) node (-B) {} -- (0,0.5) node (-C) {} -- cycle;},
  small triangle/.pic={%
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (-A) {} -- ({0.25*sqrt(2)},0) node (-B) {} -- (0,{0.25*sqrt(2)}) node (-C) {} -- cycle;},
  square/.pic={%
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (-A) {} -- ({0.25*sqrt(2)},0) node (-B) {} -- ({0.25*sqrt(2)},{0.25*sqrt(2)}) node (-C) {} --
                       (0,{0.25*sqrt(2)}) node (-D) {} -- cycle;},
  parallelogram/.pic={%
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) node (-A) {} -- (0.5,0) node (-B) {} --++ (0.25,0.25) node (-C) {} --++
                       (-0.5,0) node (-D) {} -- cycle;},
  bt1/.style={% big triangle 1
    very thin,draw=black,fill=green!50!black,line cap=round,line join=round},
  bt2/.style={% big triangle 2
    very thin,draw=black,fill=red,line cap=round,line join=round},
  mt/.style={% medium triangle
    very thin,draw=black,fill=orange,line cap=round,line join=round},
  st1/.style={% small triangle 1
    very thin,draw=black,fill=brown,line cap=round,line join=round},
  st2/.style={% small triangle 2
    very thin,draw=black,fill=blue!50!black,line cap=round,line join=round},
  sq/.style={% square
    very thin,draw=black,fill=yellow,line cap=round,line join=round},
  pr/.style={% parallelogram
    very thin,draw=black,fill=blue,line cap=round,line join=round},
}
% tangram
\pic[bt1,rotate= 45] (BT1)                           {big triangle};
\pic[bt2,rotate=135] (BT2)                           {big triangle};
\pic[mt ,rotate= 90] (MT) at (BT1-B|-BT2-C)          {medium triangle};
\pic[st1,rotate=-45]      at ($(BT1-A)!0.5!(BT1-B)$) {small triangle};
\pic[sq ,rotate=-45]                                 {square};
\pic[st2,rotate=225]                                 {small triangle};
\pic[pr]                  at (BT2-C)                 {parallelogram};
% first monk
\pic[mt ,rotate= 90] (M1) at (2,-0.5)                        {medium triangle};
\pic[bt1,rotate=135] (M2) at (M1-B)                          {big triangle};
\pic[bt2,rotate=-45] (M3) at (M2-B)                          {big triangle};
\pic[st1,rotate=-45] (M4) at ($(M2-B)+(225:{0.25*sqrt(2)})$) {small triangle};
\pic[sq]             (M5) at ($(M3-C)-({0.125*sqrt(2)},0)$)  {square};
\pic[st2,rotate=225]      at ($(M5-C)!0.5!(M5-D)+(0,0.25)$)  {small triangle};
\pic[pr]                  at ($(M2-B)-(0.5,0)$)              {parallelogram};
% second monk
\pic[mt]             (N1) at (3,-0.5)                                           {medium triangle};
\pic[st1,rotate= 90]      at ($(N1-A)!0.5!(N1-B)-(0,{0.25*sqrt(2)})$)           {small triangle};
\pic[bt1,rotate=180] (N2) at ($(N1-B)+(0,{0.5*sqrt(2)})$)                       {big triangle};
\pic[bt2,rotate=450] (N3 )at (N2-A)                                             {big triangle};
\pic[sq]             (N4) at ($(N3-B)-({0.125*sqrt(2)},0)$)                     {square};
\pic[st2,rotate=225]      at ($(N4-C)!0.5!(N4-D)+(0,0.25)$)                     {small triangle};
\pic[pr]                  at ($(N3-B)!0.5!(N3-C)-(0.5,0)-(45:{0.125*sqrt(2)})$) {parallelogram};
% OP figure (candle?)
\pic[bt1,rotate=225] (P1) at (5,0)                                     {big triangle};
\pic[bt2,rotate= 45] (P2) at (P1-A)                                    {big triangle};
\pic[sq]             (P3) at ($(P2-B)!0.5!(P2-C)-({0.125*sqrt(2)},0)$) {square};
\pic[pr,rotate={atan(3)}] at ($(P3-C)!0.5!(P3-D)$)                     {parallelogram};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is another way to do it. A better way, I'd say. It has more code (more lines) but I think that it's more legible.

I added anchors in the `pic`s (all vertices and all edge midpoints). I still use the `calc` library for placing all the coordinates. I changed the scale, as the OP requested. Also I made only one `pic` for the triangles, with a size parameter. This is the new code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/triangle/.style n args={3}{% name, anchor, size (1,2,3)
    code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\l{0.5*pow(sqrt(2),#3+1)}% cathetus length
    \coordinate (A-aux) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B-aux) at (\l,0);
    \coordinate (C-aux) at (0,\l);
    \coordinate (D-aux) at (0.5*\l,0);
    \coordinate (E-aux) at (0.5*\l,0.5*\l);
    \coordinate (F-aux) at (0,0.5*\l);
    \foreach\i in {A,...,F}
      \coordinate (#1-\i) at ($(\i-aux)-(#2-aux)$);
    \path[pic actions] (#1-A) -- (#1-B) -- (#1-C) -- cycle;
    }},
  pics/square/.style 2 args={% name, anchor
    code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\l{1}% edge length
    \coordinate (A-aux) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B-aux) at (\l,0);
    \coordinate (C-aux) at (\l,\l);
    \coordinate (D-aux) at (0,\l);
    \coordinate (E-aux) at (0.5*\l,0);
    \coordinate (F-aux) at (\l,0.5*\l);
    \coordinate (G-aux) at (0.5*\l,\l);
    \coordinate (H-aux) at (0,0.5*\l);
    \foreach\i in {A,...,H}
      \coordinate (#1-\i) at ($(\i-aux)-(#2-aux)$);
    \path[pic actions] (#1-A) -- (#1-B) -- (#1-C) -- (#1-D) -- cycle;
    }},
  pics/parallelogram/.style 2 args={% name, anchor
    code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\l{sqrt(2)}% big edge length
    \coordinate (A-aux) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B-aux) at (\l,0);
    \coordinate (C-aux) at (1.5*\l,0.5*\l);
    \coordinate (D-aux) at (0.5*\l,0.5*\l);
    \coordinate (E-aux) at (0.5*\l,0);
    \coordinate (F-aux) at (1.25*\l,0.25*\l);
    \coordinate (G-aux) at (\l,0.5*\l);
    \coordinate (H-aux) at (0.25*\l,0.25*\l);
    \foreach\i in {A,...,H}
      \coordinate (#1-\i) at ($(\i-aux)-(#2-aux)$);
    \path[pic actions] (#1-A) -- (#1-B) -- (#1-C) -- (#1-D) -- cycle;
    }},
  tangram/.style={%
    very thin,draw,line cap=round,line join=round},
  bt1/.style={% big triangle 1
    tangram,fill=red},
  bt2/.style={% big triangle 2
    tangram,fill=green!50!black},
  mt/.style={% medium triangle
    tangram,fill=orange},
  st1/.style={% small triangle 1
    tangram,fill=brown},
  st2/.style={% small triangle 2
    tangram,fill=blue!50!black},
  sq/.style={% square
    tangram,fill=yellow},
  pr/.style={% parallelogram
    tangram,fill=blue},
  solution/.style={%
    tangram,draw=red,fill=white},
  puzzle/.style={%
    tangram,fill=black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% tangram
\pic[bt1,rotate=135]           {triangle     ={T1}{C}{3}};
\pic[bt2,rotate= 45] at (T1-B) {triangle     ={T2}{C}{3}};
\pic[st1,rotate=-45] at (T2-B) {triangle     ={T3}{C}{1}};
\pic[mt ,rotate= 90] at (T3-B) {triangle     ={T4}{B}{2}};
\pic[st2,rotate=225] at (T1-A) {triangle     ={T5}{A}{1}};
\pic[sq ,rotate=-45] at (T1-A) {square       ={T6}{A}};
\pic[pr            ] at (T1-C) {parallelogram={T7}{A}};
% first monk
\pic[mt ,rotate= 90] at (5 ,0) {triangle     ={M1}{C}{2}};
\pic[bt1,rotate=-45] at (M1-B) {triangle     ={M2}{B}{3}};
\pic[bt2,rotate=135] at (M1-C) {triangle     ={M3}{C}{3}};
\pic[st1,rotate=-45] at (M2-A) {triangle     ={M4}{C}{1}};
\pic[sq            ] at (M2-C) {square       ={M5}{E}};
\pic[st2,rotate=225] at (M5-G) {triangle     ={M6}{E}{1}};
\pic[pr            ] at (M3-B) {parallelogram={M7}{B}};
% second monk
\pic[mt            ] at (9 ,0) {triangle     ={N1}{A}{2}};
\pic[bt1,rotate=180] at (N1-B) {triangle     ={N2}{C}{3}};
\pic[bt2,rotate= 90] at (N2-A) {triangle     ={N3}{A}{3}};
\pic[st1,rotate= 90] at (N1-D) {triangle     ={N4}{B}{1}};
\pic[sq            ] at (N3-B) {square       ={N5}{E}};
\pic[st2,rotate=225] at (N5-G) {triangle     ={N6}{E}{1}};
\pic[pr            ] at (N3-E) {parallelogram={N7}{F}};
% OP figure (candle?)
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{atan(3)} % rotation angle for the parallelogram
\pic[bt2,rotate=225] at (13,0) {triangle     ={P1}{B}{3}};
\pic[bt1,rotate= 45] at (P1-A) {triangle     ={P2}{A}{3}};
\pic[sq            ] at (P2-E) {square       ={P3}{E}};
\pic[pr ,rotate= \a] at (P3-G) {parallelogram={P4}{A}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both codes render essentially the same picture:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I added two more styles for puzzles and solutions as the OP requested, but they are not used in the above picture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will review your code and apply it. Just one comment. How can I set a magnification factor, as I did in my code?

Comment: @Hany, just add a `scale` with the `transform shape` option, as in `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,transform shape]`, or whatever factor you need.

Comment: @– Juan Castaño. Thank you very much for your solution. How to define 2 styles for all the shapes, one as a solution (with draw=red, fill=white); and one as a puzzle (with draw=black, fill=black)

Comment: @Hany, I made another edit and added the new styles in the second code (which I think is more clear).

Comment: @– Juan Castaño  Thank you very much for your well done solution. Just one comment. You added a solution style and a puzzle style. Now how to apply the puzzle style to draw black-filled shapes instead of the coloured shapes?

Comment: @Hany, you only have to change the styles in the `pic` declaration. For example, change the first triangle `\pic[bt1,rotate=135]{triangle={T1}{C}{3}};` for `\pic[puzzle,rotate=135]{triangle={T1}{C}{3}};`or `\pic[solution,rotate=135]{triangle={T1}{C}{3}};` and you'll see the styles applied.

Comment: @– Juan Castaño  Thank you very much for your time and concern. One last comment (I hope). There are 2 parallelograms used in my code, (parallelogram, and parallelogramr). How to draw the parallelogramr in your code.  In my code they are:   parallelogram/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;
  },   and   
  parallelogramr/.pic={%to flip horizontally
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,-1) -- (1,-1) -- cycle;
  }

Comment: @Hany, you can achieve both parallelograms only with one `pic`. To flip it horizontally add the option `x=-1cm`. For example in the candle change `\pic[pr,rotate=\a] at (P3-G) {parallelogram={P4}{A}};` for `\pic[pr,rotate=-\a,x=-1cm] at (P3-G) {parallelogram={P4}{A}};`. Note that as you are changing the axis you need to change the rotation angle too.

Comment: @– Juan Castaño I used your modified last code, after applying your remarks. It is perfect. Thank you very very much for your time and concern.

Answer (score 3):

I think on reflection that I prefer Juan's answer, but as I commented that I thought my `penrose` package could help then here's a starting point for using it for tangrams.  What it does well is align one tile with another along an edge.  What it doesn't do so well is allow that alignment to be at an arbitrary point along the edge.  The package is designed primarily for tilings where edges match exactly and in tangram packages then that isn't a requirement.  Nevertheless, it may be possible to adapt the tools of the penrose package, or to tweak them slightly, to make them work in a more intuitive fashion.

The following code defines the tiles and then uses the alignment to put them together into the standard square.  This works in MikTeX and TeXLive, but might need both to be up-to-date (in particular, MikTeX might not spot that the penrose package needs updating since it is a tikz library rather than an actual package0.

For an explanation of how the alignment works, see the penrose package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603673/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{penrose}


\DefineTile{big triangle}{1 1 1}
{
 {0,0}
 {2,0}
 {2,2}
}

\DefineTile{medium triangle}{1 1 1}
{
 {0,0}
 {2,0}
 {1,1}
}

\DefineTile{small triangle}{1 1 1}
{
 {0,0}
 {1,0}
 {1,1}
}

\DefineTile{parallelogram}{1 1 1 1}
{
  {0,0}
  {1,0}
  {2,1}
  {1,1}
}

\DefineTile{square}{1 1 1 1}
{
  {0,0}
  {1,0}
  {1,1}
  {0,1}
}


\tikzset{clone Penrose side path={1}{a}}
\BakePenroseTile{big triangle}
\BakePenroseTile{medium triangle}
\BakePenroseTile{small triangle}
\BakePenroseTile{parallelogram}
\BakePenroseTile{square}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every Penrose tile/.style={draw=black, fill=green}]
\pic[big triangle, name = A];
\pic[big triangle, name = B, align with=A along 12 using 1];
\pic[small triangle, name = C, align with=A along 11 using 2];
\pic[square, name = D, align with=C along 11 using 1];
\pic[small triangle, name = E, align with=D along 13 using 2];
\pic[parallelogram, name = F, align with=E along 13 using 2];
\pic[medium triangle, name=G, align with=D along 12 using 1];
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: tangrams automatically aligned]

Comment: I appear not to have allowed for applying a transformation _after_ a tile is aligned against another tile.  This seems something of an oversight and one that I will fix next time I'm messing with the code.